# Swift 4 attributedString get typing attributes

Tags: swift, ios11, swift4, xcode9

I am trying to create AttributedString and add the attributes from

`typingAttributes(from textView)`

The problem is that

`.typingAttributes`

return

`[String, Any]`

and

`NSAttributedString(string:.. , attributes:[])`

needs

`[NSAttributedStringKey: Any]`

My code:

```
NSAttributedString(string: "test123", attributes: self.textView.typingAttributes)
```

I don't want to create for in cycle to go through all keys and change them to

```
NSAttributedStringKey
```

Comment: I wonder *why* the keys in the typingAttributes dictionaries a strings and not NSAttributedStringKey. You may want to file a bug report.

Comment: I will but for now I want to make it work

Comment: Looks like there are two open radars addressing variations of this: https://openradar.appspot.com/34994725 and https://openradar.appspot.com/34402659

Comment: I reported the bug a month ago and still no response from Apple. DOn't worry.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can map the `[String: Any]` dictionary to a
`[NSAttributedStringKey: Any]` dictionary with

```
let typingAttributes = Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues: self.textView.typingAttributes.map {
    key, value in (NSAttributedStringKey(key), value)
})

let text = NSAttributedString(string: "test123", attributes: typingAttributes)
```

Here is a possible extension method for that purpose, it is 
restricted to dictionaries with string keys:

```
extension Dictionary where Key == String {

    func toAttributedStringKeys() -> [NSAttributedStringKey: Value] {
        return Dictionary<NSAttributedStringKey, Value>(uniqueKeysWithValues: map {
            key, value in (NSAttributedStringKey(key), value)
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Even better solution I think. I created extension.

```
public extension Dictionary {
    func toNSAttributedStringKeys() -> [NSAttributedStringKey: Any] {
        var atts = [NSAttributedStringKey: Any]()

        for key in keys {
            if let keyString = key as? String {
                atts[NSAttributedStringKey(keyString)] = self[key]
            }
        }

        return atts
    }
}
```

https://gist.github.com/AltiAntonov/f0f86e7cd04c61118e13f753191b5d9e

Comment: Good idea. – If you restrict the extension to string keys then the optional cast is not needed. I have added a simpler version to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my helper class, which I use custom fonts

```
import UIKit

struct AttributedStringHelper {

enum FontType: String {
    case bold = "GothamRounded-Bold"
    case medium = "GothamRounded-Medium"
    case book = "GothamRounded-Book"
}

static func getString(text: String, fontType: FontType, size: CGFloat, color: UIColor, isUnderlined: Bool? = nil) -> NSAttributedString {

    var attributes : [NSAttributedStringKey : Any] = [
        NSAttributedStringKey(rawValue: NSAttributedStringKey.font.rawValue) : UIFont(name: fontType.rawValue, size: size)!,
        NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor : color]

    if let isUnderlined = isUnderlined, isUnderlined {
        attributes[NSAttributedStringKey.underlineStyle] = 1
    }

    let attributedString = NSAttributedString(string: text, attributes: attributes)
    return attributedString
}
}
```